# Navigation Drawer error while opening a new fragment

Tags: javascript, android

My code:

MainActivity.java:

```
mainDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mainDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mainDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);

    mainDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mainDrawerToggle);
    mainDrawerToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    setupDrawerContent();

Fragment myFragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass;
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_aboutus;
            fragmentClass = AboutUs.class;
            break;
            default:
                fragmentClass = AboutUs.class;
    }
    try {
        myFragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flcontent,myFragment).commit();
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
    mainDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
}
    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            selectItemDrawer(item);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

When I trying this method, I don't know what can I write to  ""setupDrawerContent();"" here.... and here "`case R.id.nav_aboutus;`" I have this error:  "`Error:(48, 34) error: : expected`"

*Edit*
I started the whole app in "Blank Activity"

Can anyone help me?
Thanks..

*EDIT2* :  http://www.mediafire.com/file/i0gn3qgcbw4c5jn/TheWhole%20Code.rar

Comment: You didn't pass the navigationView as parameter on setupDrawerContent method. I sugges to read more about Java.

Comment: And how can I pass it?

Comment: Show your whole code, where did you set findViewById on your navigationView? That's what you're going to pass. setupDrawerContent(yourNavigationView);

Comment: That is a basic question (sorry for that :P) : Where can I find the NavigationView; There, where are the items (where's my nav_menu)?

Comment: My comment answers how you can pass it (which you don't understand, well). We can't find it because you didn't show also your full code. It seems that you don't fully the Java language. You've got error on case R.id.nav_aboutus because you use semi colon instead of colon. That's just a basic syntax of switch case statement. Please read more about Java Language.

Comment: Okay, thank for you answer. I make an another edit, in which i show you the whole code.